# JavaEE: Unit test custom request wrapper

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I have a custom wrapper class around an httpServletRequest object. The purpose of the wrapper is to validate the parameters against whitelists before sending the request on through the filterChain.

The issue I'm having is that I have overridden the getParameter method of the standard request object in the wrapper; It checks if the parameter is in a hashmap, and if so it will perform validation on the parameter using an instance of another class. How can I unit test the getParameter method, considering i cant set the query string or set parameters onto the object? I have created unit tests for the actual object(Class that utilises Esapi.Validator()) that checks if the parameter value is valid input and returns a boolean value back to the wrapper, so is it even worth my time testing the wrapper?

TestRequestWrapper.java

```
public class TestRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper{
    private static HashMap<String, EsapiParameterValidator> validationMap = new HashMap<String, EsapiParameterValidator>();
    static{
       /* esapiParameterValidator takes the param name, 
        * name of regex in Esapi.properties, field length 
        * and boolean indicating if the parameter can be null
        */
        validationMap.put("lob", new EsapiParameterValidator("lob", "REG.lob", 3, false));
       // number of other entries
    }

    public TestRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request){
        super(request);
    }

    public String getParameter(String parameter){
        String value = super.getParameter(parameter);
        if(validationMap.containsKey(parameter)){
            EsapiParameterValidator epv = validationMap.get(parameter);  
            value = epv.getValidatedParam(value) ? value : "";
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: Why can't you "set parameters onto the object" ? If HttpServletREquest doesn't allow you then write/use an implementation that does or pass in a mock HttpServletRequest in your test

Comment: but then the request will have a blank query string surely, if i pass in a mock? the request can have a variety of parameters but there is only around 5 or so that i need to validate. I tried passing in a mock httpServletRequest into the testRequestWrapper object, but i cant call getParameter because the ones I need to validate arent on the object

Comment: If you mock HttpServletRequest using a framework then you might end up having to mock lots of method calls to get the values you want in your test e.g. getQueryString or seomthing. It's probably easier to pass in an implementation like Spring's MockHttpServletRequest where you can set up the values you require.

Comment: ah I see, what part of the Spring framework would I need to access that object?

Comment: I think it's in Spring Test

Comment: Yes this worked, the MockHttpServletRequest object provided the functionality i needed. To be honest Im a little surprised that mutable Request objects aren't available in other standalone mocking frameworks, e.g. easymock or Mockito